# glReadPixel doesn't work in OnPick function

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

i try to implement 3D picking in an android app. I use OpenGL ES2.0.

Now I want to read the depth buffer (which is written in an FBO) but glReadPixels returns only 0.
The code is correct, because I tried the same code after calling my RenderInTexture function and it returns the correct values. 
Calling RenderInTexture in the OnPick function and than call glReadPixels returns also 0.

What is the problem?
Isn't it possible to read a framebuffer in the OnPick event or do i have to set some variables?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the OnPick called on the main (UI) thread? Probably you have two threads, the opengl rendering thread and the main application thread where events are sent. Try storing the onpick coordinates in you OnPick method and do the computation in the opengl thread.

Hope that helps.